# Connecting 2 Pixhawks to 1 Raspberry Pi

Tags: quadcopters, troubleshooting, software, raspberry-pi

I want to connect my Raspberry pi 4 to two Pixhawks such that when I'm using one other will be in sleep mode.

One way of doing it is by assigning address to an individual and then switching. But I'm not getting how to do it, or is there any other way I can do this.

Even a small guidance will help.

Comment: Do you mean to have one powered up but in 'reset'? Or do you want to remove power from one? I don't see any means of holding a PixHawk 4 in reset.

Comment: I mean one will have have ardusub or ardurover firmware other will have ardupilot.
When I'm in air I want to use ardupilot when I'm in water or land ardusub or ardu rover
Such that when I'm using one other will  go to sleep and it can switch to pix 2 from pix 1 and vice versa . The non usable puxhawk will be on standby

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I've edited your question to attempt to clarify your exact issue.  If any of the edits conflict with your intent, please feel free to [edit] to clarify.  Also, you can take the [tour] to earn a badge, and visit the [help] for more details on how to write a great question for this site.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Ardupilot there are parameters `SYSID_THISMAV` and `SYSID_MYGCS` that can be set to different values. This may only be helpful for MavLink. I have no experience with this so I am not sure if it would help with your plans.

One way to accomplish the switching would be to use a relay board and switch the power between the two PixHawk boards. Only one will be powered, so I am not sure that meets your definition of *Standby*.

I do see some other potential problems, especially if you want to share some resources like GPS, Receiver, etc. between the two PixHawk.